# How to solve the incorrect syntax near 'Transaction'?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I want to insert data to the DataTable from the user. I get this exception : "Exception :  incorrect syntax near the Transaction".  I tried to find the syntax error but I could not solve it.

```
public void Add_to_Transaction(SqlConnection conn , int serial_number ,  DataTable dt)
{
   try
   {
      //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
      cmd1.Connection = conn;
      cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Transaction";
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
      adapter.SelectCommand = cmd1;
      adapter.Fill(dt);

      SqlParameter serial_number1 = new SqlParameter("product_id",serial_number);
      SqlParameter quantity = new SqlParameter("quantity", 0);
      SqlParameter date = new SqlParameter("date", DateTime.Today);
      cmd1.Parameters.Add(serial_number1);
      cmd1.Parameters.Add(quantity);
      cmd1.Parameters.Add(date);
      Console.WriteLine("111111111111111111");

      cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction (quantity,date,product_id) VALUES (@quantity,@date,@product_id)";
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

      Console.WriteLine("222222222222222222");

      cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
 }
```

Comment: "Tatabransaction"? Are you typing that wrong here or in your program?

Comment: needle in a haystack comes to mind... what line is causing the error?

Comment: You have a stray ' before @product_id

Comment: Transaction is a key word, van you have a table called transaction? What DB are you using?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Transaction]` to avoid the reference of sql keyword.

Comment: @DogEars that comment is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are words in  T-SQL which are reserved keywords. You cannot use them directly in sql without using brackets around them. So either choose different names for these columns or tablenames or use brackets `[forbiddenword]` around them:

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction] (quantity,date,product_id) VALUES (@quantity,@date,@product_id);
SELECT * FROM [Transaction];
```

[**Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [Transaction]
```

Putting words in `[ ]` makes SQL know it's not a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction` is a key word.
Is this what you meant?